# Unicode Decode ErrorL Ordinal not in range

Tags: unicode, encoding

so I am trying to make the values in a csv file Unicode so a program I am using is able to read them. Here is my code, in Python 2.7, which I HAVE to use:

```
 TEST_SENTENCES = []
    with open('Book2.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            encoded_tweet = row["Tweet"].encode('utf-8')
            TEST_SENTENCES.append(encoded_tweet)
```

I continue to receive the same error message, and have not been able to find anything that works. Here is the error message. I am sure someone out there can make a really easy solution.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 127: ordinal not in range(128)
```

As an update, I changed encode to decode, and the program says it is running the predictions, given it has been a while but it would not have started if it was not encoded in Unicode so let us pray.

Comment: Provide a sample of the .csv that reproduces the issue, and a [mcve] along with the full traceback of the error message.  The stock `csv` module in Python 2.7 doesn't support Unicode so you read raw encoded data, and should be decoding it to Unicode, not encoding it.  You're getting the `UnicodeDecodeError`, because you can't encode a byte string, so Python 2.7 is "helpful" and decodes it with the default ASCII codec, hence your error.  Also see the [examples at the bottom of the csv documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#examples) for dealing with Unicode.

Comment: You could also use [unicodecsv](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv).  If you have `pip` configured you can do `py -m pip install unicodecsv`.